# How to increase font-size of Text in ShowLegend

Tags: plotting, legending, fonts

The default font-size of `Legend` text generated using `ShowLegend[]` is too small. How does one increase this? The code I am working with is:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
LstTest = Flatten[Table[{i, j, (i + j)/200}, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}], 1];
plTest = ListContourPlot[LstTest, Contours -> 9, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
LMax = Max[LstTest[[All, 3]]]; LMin = Min[LstTest[[All, 3]]];

ShowLegend[plTest, 
           {ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1] &, 
            10, 
            ToString[Round[LMax, 0.01]], 
            ToString[Round[LMin, 0.01]], 
            LegendPosition -> {0.6, 0}
           }
          ]
```

The `0.01` and `1.0` appear too small, and I would like to increase the font-size of these. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Nasser try `Needs["PlotLegends"]`, that should at least give you the legend.

Comment: @Nasser I totally agree with that. I just hope the OP will keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: Sorry! I thought the data can be generated quite easily. I have made it complete now. Also, I am using Mathematica 8.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];

Manipulate[

 ShowLegend[
  plTest,
  {ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1] &,
   10,
   ToString[Round[LMax, 0.01]],
   ToString[Round[LMin, 0.01]],
   LegendPosition -> {0.6, 0},
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> n}
   }
  ],

 {{n, 12, "how big?"}, 4, 16, 1,Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 Initialization :>
  (
   LstTest = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {10}, {10}, {10}];
   plTest = ListContourPlot[LstTest, Contours -> 9,ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
   LMax = 1.0; LMin = 0.79;
   )
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great! Thanks @Nasser. That works! From next time, I will post complete code. Sorry about this.